# axios interceptor not displaying error message when I get a 401 response from backend

Tags: javascript, axios, interceptor

I am trying to send for a refresh token when token expires.

But when the token expires and I get 401 unauthenticated error

the response error is not called.

`console.log('error from second config ', error?.response)` does not dispay anything

```js
import axios from "axios";

// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    // const loggedIn = token.isTokenLogged();
    console.log("response from first config ", config);
    const loggedIn =
      localStorage.getItem("_token") !== ""
        ? localStorage.getItem("_token")
        : "";
    if (loggedIn) {
      console.log("logged in ", loggedIn);
      config.headers = {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      };
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${loggedIn}`;
      console.log(config);
    } else {
      console.log("There is no token yet...");
    }
    // config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    return config;
  },
  async (error) => {
    console.log("error from second config ", error?.response?.status);

    Promise.reject(error);
  },
);
const refreshToken = async () => {
  try {
    const resp = await axios.get("auth/refresh");
    console.log("refresh token", resp.data);
    return resp.data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error", e);
  }
};
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  function (response) {
    return response;
  },
  function (error) {
    console.log("error from second config ", error?.response);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);
export default axios;
```

Comment: please explain what you mean by 'console.log('error from second config ', error?.response) does not dispay anything' does string 'error from second config' not show at all?

Comment: Looks like a simple **typo**. If you want a **response** interceptor, you should add it to `axios.interceptors.response`.